# How to fix outo slider triggeruing multiple times in horizontal pager migration problem from accompanist to foundation compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have used `accompanist` library with older version like `0.22` as far as I know `accompanist is deprecated`, I made a migration to `foundation` -> `import androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager`. And now my problem is:
I have auto logic to get auto slider every 3 seconds also I am available to manually change the actual image on the slider. When I do it manually it starts to triggers multiple time like `LaunchedEffect` starts trigger that many times as it was done manually. If I do not do anything and only auto slider works it is fine. I haven't that problem with accompanist.
The only change is library and fix for this version I had to make with adding `coroutineScope.launch {}` in `LaunchedEffect`

```
        LaunchedEffect("${state.currentPage}") {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    delay(AUTO_SLIDER_DELAY)
                    if (state.pageCount != 0) {
                        var newPosition = state.currentPage + 1
                        if (newPosition > sliderItems.size - 1) newPosition = 0
                        state.animateScrollToPage(newPosition.mod(state.pageCount))
                    }
            }
        }
```

```
         HorizontalPager(
                        state = state
                    ) { page ->
   
                                    AsyncBlurryImage(
                                        imageUrl = imageUrl.value,
                                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                                        contentDescription = null,
                                        modifier = Modifier
                                            .aspectRatio(1.77f)
[...]
```

I see the problem could be that now my external coroutine logic which is created out of `LaunchedEffect` does not stop during the recomposition how to refix it?